# Weird behavior when changing parts of matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have this matrix:

```
mat = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, {16, 
    17, 18, 19, 20}, {21, 22, 23, 24, 25}};
```

and here are its second row and second column:

```
{mat[[2]], mat[[All, 2]]}
(* {{6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {2, 7, 12, 17, 22}} *)
```

When I tried to change its second column to all zeros, this method works:

```
mat = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, {16, 
    17, 18, 19, 20}, {21, 22, 23, 24, 25}};
mat[[All, 2]] = 0;
mat // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But using the method to change the second row, the entire row become a big zero:

```
mat = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, {16, 
    17, 18, 19, 20}, {21, 22, 23, 24, 25}};
mat[[2]] = 0;
mat // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**My question is:**

**1)** Why would the replacement of a row versus a column in a matrix different?

**2)** Why would setting the list of all column elements to zero automatically set each of them to zero? Setting a list to a single number doesn't seem to work in isolation:

```
{a, b, c} = 0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I think this behavior is correct, because what if I wanted the second element of the list `mat` to be `0`? This is the logical way to do that.

Comment: I think it's correct too. The part that I found confusing is more on the replacement of the column, which by this method seems to be an element-by-element replacement (instead of replacing a whole row to a single 0 in comparison). If so, I can't see how setting a list of all these column elements would set them all to zero instead of, say, giving me an error. Also, doing this doesn't seem to work:`mat = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18, 19, 20}, {21, 22, 23, 24, 25}};
{mat[[1, 2]], mat[[2, 2]], mat[[3, 2]], mat[[4, 2]], mat[[5, 2]]} = 0;
mat`.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, I think the reason it works like this is because *Mathematica* lists can be anything, so it assumed you want the second element of this list of lists to be `0`. So if you want all elements of that second sublist to be `0`, you have to specify it just like you did for the column.

```
mat = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, {16, 
    17, 18, 19, 20}, {21, 22, 23, 24, 25}};
```

Then:

```
mat[[2, All]] = 0
```

OR

```
mat[[2, ;;]] = 0

mat // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hm... you changed your answer and now mine is rather a duplicate.  Nevertheless I stated things a bit differently so I'm going to leave it, if you don't mind.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, it's fine, I don't mind.

Comment: By the way I want to let you know that I have noticed the rapid "reputation" gain you've made over the last few weeks – impressive!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thanks. It means a lot coming from you. It's probably going to slow down this week, I'm about to start writing some papers :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - As my prime moderator ("whig") you should refrain from such comments. It's like a teacher saying: "Buddy, I notice you, but I don't don't notice all the others in my class." If I may quote yourself: "As a Community Moderator my conduct should be held to a higher standard (i.e. if I'm doing it wrong people should criticize me)". I hope you don't mind my criticism. :)

Comment: @eldo I do not mind your criticism; as you quoted I welcome it.  I'll think about what you wrote.  Off-hand I don't feel this situation is equivalent to the classroom example as this is all informal and without serious consequence, but I also don't intend to show favoritism.  I congratulate people on notable accomplishments simply to be friendly, but since I'm not omniscient I'm bound to overlook some and notice others.  If this is a topic that matters to you I suggest a post on Meta, as that is the standard course to take.

Answer (score 5):

This is simply the logical outcome of *Mathematica* treating an array as an ordinary expression tree.

Your array isn't really an array at all, but merely a collection of `List` expressions inside another `List` expression, all of which happen to be the same length.  And like any other ordinary expression in an assignment you can change a part using `Set`:

```
expr = foo[bar, baz];

expr[[2]] = 0;

expr
```

> ```
> foo[bar, 0]
> ```

While *Mathematica* can store a true array in the case of packed arrays these are handled in such a way as to make operations behave identically to the same operation on the equivalent ordinary expression.  (There are exception but I digress.)

If you wish to zero all values within a row you can specially address all parts of the row as RunnyKine did, with e.g. `a[[2, All]] = 0;`, or you can simply multiply the row by `0`, since `Times` is a `Listable` operation:

```
a = Partition[Range@9, 3];

a[[2]] *= 0;

a
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {7, 8, 9}}
> ```