# Replacing columns of a matrix with zeros

Tags: functions, matrix, replacement

I am to create a function that replaces columns 'm' through till 'n' with zeros. Here is what I have so far:

```
zeroColumns[mat_, m_ ;; n_] := ReplacePart[mat, {_, m | n} -> 0]
list1 = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 4}, {4, 5, 6, 9, 5}, {7, 3, 8, 9, 5}, {14, 3, 1,5, 6}}
zeroColumns[list1, 1 ;; 3]
```

which returns

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 4}, {4, 5, 6, 9, 5}, {7, 3, 8, 9, 5}, {14, 3, 1, 5, 6}}
>
> {{0, 2, 0, 4, 4}, {0, 5, 0, 9, 5}, {0, 3, 0, 9, 5}, {0, 3, 0, 5, 6}}
> ```

and that's not a surprise to me because in the part `ReplacePart[list1, {_, m | n} -> 0]` I'm not going from 'm' to 'n'; instead, I'm choosing column 'm' and column 'n'. I tried replacing `|` with `;;` but it does nothing. How can I iterate from 'm' to 'n' instead of just picking both? I cannot use loops. I'm not really interested in revamping my code. I'm sure there's just a simple way of altering the `|` so that it goes through EVERY column instead of just THOSE two.

Comment: Related: [(3069)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3077/121), [(52385)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/52385/121).  Possible duplicate: [(56494)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56494/121)

Answer (score 11):

```
ClearAll[zeroColumns2,zeroColumns2b,zeroColumns3,zeroColumns3b];
zeroColumns2[mat_, m_ ;; n_] :=  ReplacePart[mat, {_, Alternatives @@ Range[m, n]} -> 0];
(* or Alternatives @@ Range @@ (m ;; n) if you want to use Span *)

list1 = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 4}, {4, 5, 6, 9, 5}, {7, 3, 8, 9, 5}, {14, 3, 1, 5, 6}};
zeroColumns2[list1, 1 ;; 3]
(* {{0,0,0,4,4},{0,0,0,9,5},{0,0,0,9,5},{0,0,0,5,6}} *)
```

A way to use `Span` instead of `Alternatives`:

```
zeroColumns2b[mat_, m_ ;; n_] := ReplacePart[mat, Thread[{_, Range @@ (m ;; n)}] -> 0];
```

Just in case you don't *have to* use `ReplacePart`, you might consider

```
zeroColumns3[mat_, m_ ;; n_] := Module[{t = mat}, t[[All, m ;; n]] = 0; t]
zeroColumns3[list1, 1 ;; 3]
(* {{0,0,0,4,4},{0,0,0,9,5},{0,0,0,9,5},{0,0,0,5,6}}  *)
```

or, without `Module`,

```
ClearAll[zeroColumns2c];
SetAttributes[zeroColumns2c, HoldFirst];
zeroColumns2c[mat_, m_ ;; n_] := (mat[[All, m ;; n]] = 0; mat);
zeroColumns2c[list1, 1 ;; 3]
(*  {{0,0,0,4,4},{0,0,0,9,5},{0,0,0,9,5},{0,0,0,5,6}}  *)
```

Note: This last one modifies the input matrix in-place.

Comment: Thanks very much, although I wish I could somehow use `;;` in place of `|`. We're supposed to be using pure functions right now, and not modules.

Comment: I suppose you could do something like this then `MapAt[#*0&,list1,{All,1;;3}]`

Comment: You have my vote, but please note for readers that the final method ("without `Module`") modifies in-place.

Comment: It seems to me that `Range @@ (m ;; n)` is simply `Range[m,n]`. So may be `s_Span` instead of `m_ ;; n_`? You will handle `m ;; n ;; d` at the same time.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thanks. Good point; will update.

Comment: Be careful of `All`, explicit or otherwise.

Comment: Mr.Wizard, @ybeltukov, it looks like there are quite a few traps to watch for when attempting to make it more general :)

Answer (score 10):

An alternative approach

```
m = RandomInteger[9, {5, 5}];
m // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
MapAt[0 &, m, {;; , 2 ;; 4}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

---

There is a pattern-based solution, but it is considerably more diffiluct

```
zeroColumns4[mat_, s_Span] := 
  ReplacePart[mat, {_, j_ /; s[[1]] <= j <= (s[[2]] /. All -> ∞) && 
     (Length@s < 3 || Mod[j - s[[1]], s[[3]]] == 0)} -> 0];

m = RandomInteger[9, {10, 10}];
m // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
zeroColumns4[m, 4 ;; ;; 2] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: +1 If the OP's goal is to leave everything in the original code unchanged except `m | n`, then I suggest `zeroColumns[mat_, m_ ;; n_] := ReplacePart[mat, {_, i_ /; m <= i <= n} -> 0]`.

Answer (score 4):

I understand from a comment that the use of pure functions is desired, but I think the broader question will have a broader interest.  Here's a way that has a little start-up time, but whose efficiency advantage increases with size.

```
zeroColumnsM[mat_?MatrixQ, m_ ;; n_] := 
 With[{ncol = Last@Dimensions@mat}, 
  mat . SparseArray[Delete[Table[{i, i} -> 1, {i, ncol}], List /@ Range[m, n]], {ncol,ncol}]
  ]

zeroColumnsM[list1, 2 ;; 3]
(* {{1, 0, 0, 4, 4}, {4, 0, 0, 9, 5}, {7, 0, 0, 9, 5}, {14, 0, 0, 5, 6}} *)
```

Timings:  Originally, I omitted [kguler's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kguler) `zeroColumns3`, which is probably as fast as one can get because of comments on the use of `Module`.  Later I realized that if I'm going to consider the "broader question," then it definitely should be included.

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];

zeroColumns2[mat_, m_ ;; n_] :=                 (* kguler's faster function *)
  ReplacePart[mat, {_, Alternatives @@ Range[m, n]} -> 0];
zeroColumns3[mat_, m_ ;; n_] := 
  Module[{t = mat}, t[[All, m ;; n]] = 0; t];   (* kguler's really faster function *)
zeroColumnsY[mat_?MatrixQ, m_ ;; n_] :=         (* ybeltukob *)
  MapAt[0 &, mat, Thread[{All, Range[m, n]}]]
```

Small example:

```
list = RandomInteger[10, {10, 10}];
res2 = zeroColumns2[list, 2 ;; 5]; // AccurateTiming
res3 = zeroColumns3[list, 2 ;; 5]; // AccurateTiming
resY = zeroColumnsY[list, 2 ;; 5]; // AccurateTiming
resM = zeroColumnsM[list, 2 ;; 5]; // AccurateTiming
```

> 0.0000805732
>   7.9209*10^-6 *
>   0.0000251982
>   0.000071834

Larger example:

```
list = RandomInteger[10, {100, 200}];
res2 = zeroColumns2[list, 20 ;; 50]; // AccurateTiming
res3 = zeroColumns3[list, 20 ;; 50]; // AccurateTiming
resY = zeroColumnsY[list, 20 ;; 50]; // AccurateTiming
resM = zeroColumnsM[list, 20 ;; 50]; // AccurateTiming
```

> 0.0176221
>   0.000024208 *
>   0.00363939
>   0.000537734

```
res2 == resY == resM
(* True *)
```

The `SparseArray` approach gains an advantage the more columns there are to be zeroed, but I doubt there's a way to beat kguler's `zeroColumns3`.

Comment: It seems that @kguler's `zeroColumns2c` is considerably faster even with an additional copying of the matrix.

Comment: @ybeltukov I didn't compare `zeroColumns2c` because it changes `mat`.  I should have tested `zeroColumns3`, though.

Comment: @MichaelE2 - Interesting, that you don't consider the other answers for your your timing table. What you got is, to quote yourself, "a lack of time."

Comment: @eldo The other answers weren't there when I did the analysis. But it's interesting that no one else has done it at all.  In part there's just so much time.  And we had to go harvest.  It's going to be cold tonight.

Comment: @MichaelE2 :)))

Comment: @Michael I happened to look at your profile and saw: "visited 666 days, 666 consecutive" -- besides the slightly interesting number I was shocked to see that you've been on the site *every day* since you joined!?  I must admit I am sort of hoping you have a script that refreshes the page.  Otherwise I think you are over due for some time away from a computer!  (And SE itself for that matter.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard A sleeping Mac turns itself on every few hours to get mail etc. It caused the open MSE page to register me as present. I turned that feature off - I took over a year to discover it - then I got a new Mac which turned the feature back on (I assumed it would inherit the old settings). Your noticing is a coincidence - for the last 5 days I've been on family trip with the computer off. If you look now, it says 667/1.  Now sometimes I would log in only at breakfast just to keep the streak going.  I'm glad you saw the 666.  Breaking the streak at that number was a coincidence, too.

Comment: @Michael I hope you enjoyed the vacation.  Amazing coincidence; glad I saw it!

Answer (score 3):

For rendering columns m through n step s:

```
sa[mat_, m_, n_, s_: 1] := 
(1-SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; MemberQ[Range[m, n, s], j] :> 1,Dimensions@mat]) mat
```

For removing list of columns:

```
sasc[mat_,list_] := 
(1-SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; MemberQ[list, j] :> 1,Dimensions@mat]) mat
```

Testing:

```
test={{9, 6, 2, 1, 1, 4, 8, 0, 8, 8}, {0, 1, 7, 8, 8, 9, 4, 3, 6, 8}, {1, 
  5, 4, 2, 8, 9, 4, 1, 9, 3}, {5, 6, 4, 3, 0, 9, 7, 7, 3, 0}, {4, 0, 
  7, 5, 3, 0, 8, 8, 1, 6}, {3, 4, 8, 8, 7, 6, 9, 6, 2, 0}, {0, 7, 7, 
  0, 8, 9, 5, 3, 0, 3}, {8, 0, 1, 7, 7, 9, 2, 3, 9, 9}, {1, 5, 6, 2, 
  7, 3, 8, 0, 7, 6}, {2, 0, 9, 8, 4, 4, 0, 1, 6, 6}}
```

[image]

```
sa[test, 2, 10, 2] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
sasc[test, {2, 3, 7}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A solution using `Set`

```
replace[m_?MatrixQ, p_?VectorQ] := Module[{q = m}, q[[All, p]] = 0; q]
```

Replace 1 column

```
replace[RandomInteger[9, {5, 5}], {3}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Replace contigious columns

```
replace[RandomInteger[9, {7, 7}], Range[2, 6]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Replace at arbitrary positions

```
replace[RandomInteger[9, {5, 5}], {1, 3, 4}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

A **variant** "directly" changing your matrix

```
Clear @ replaceInplace
SetAttributes[replaceInplace, HoldFirst]

replaceInplace[m_?MatrixQ, p_?VectorQ] := (m[[All, p]] = 0; m)

mat = RandomInteger[9, {5, 5}]; 
replaceInplace[mat, {1, 3, 4}]
mat // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
list1.DiagonalMatrix[{1, 0, 0, 0, 1}] // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\
 7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\
 14 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Or, maybe a more versatile variation:

```
list1 // #.SparseArray[{ {2, 2} -> 0, {3, 3} -> 0, {4, 4} -> 0, 
  Band[{1, 1}] -> 1}, Dimensions[#][[2]]] & // MatrixForm
```

$$  \left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\
 7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\
 14 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$