# Conditional replace of a column

Tags: functions, replacement

Im trying to replace the value in the Nth column of a list if a condition is true, returning the modified list.
I've tried modifying the answer from [61219](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61219/replacing-columns-of-a-matrix-with-zeros) and been through most of related questions but no luck.

```
dataCol = {{A, 0.1, 0.3}, {B, 0.4, 0.6}, {C, 0.9, 0.9}};
cutoffFuncCol[threshold_, inputlist_,col_] := 
(inputlist[[All, col]] /. {x_ /; x > threshold -> x, x_ /; x < threshold -> 0});
cutoffFuncCol[0.5, dataCol, 2]

(* actual result {0, 0, 0.9} *)
(* Desired result  {{A, 0.0, 0.3}, {B, 0.0, 0.6}, {C, 0.9, 0.9}}; *)
```

Comment: Your output is `{0 ,0 ,.9}` because you only work with `dataCol[[All, 2]]` which is `{.1, .4., .9}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dataCol = {{A, 0.1, 0.3}, {B, 0.4, 0.6}, {C, 0.9, 0.9}};
```

**Adding the `Attribute` `HoldRest` to your `cutoffFuncCol`:**

```
ClearAll[cutoffFuncColB];
SetAttributes[cutoffFuncColB, HoldRest];
cutoffFuncColB[threshold_, inputlist_, col_] := (inputlist[[All, col]] = 
    inputlist[[All, col]] /. {x_ /; x > threshold -> x, x_ /; x < threshold -> 0}; inputlist);

dataColB = dataCol; 
cutoffFuncColB[0.5, dataColB, 2]
(*  {{A, 0, 0.3}, {B, 0, 0.6}, {C, 0.9, 0.9}} *)
```

**Using `Threshold` instead of `ReplaceAll`:**

```
ClearAll[cutoffFuncColC];
SetAttributes[cutoffFuncColC, HoldRest];
cutoffFuncColC[threshold_, inputlist_, col_] :=
  (inputlist[[All, col]] = Threshold[inputlist[[All, col]], threshold]; inputlist);

dataColC = dataCol;
cutoffFuncColC[0.5, dataColC, 2]
(*  {{A, 0, 0.3}, {B, 0, 0.6}, {C, 0.9, 0.9}} *)
```

Or

```
ClearAll[cutoffFuncColD];
cutoffFuncColD[threshold_, inputlist_, col_] := 
 Module[{mm = inputlist},  mm[[All, col]] = Threshold[mm[[All, col]], threshold]; mm]

dataColD = dataCol;
cutoffFuncColD[0.5, dataColD, 2]
(*  {{A, 0, 0.3}, {B, 0, 0.6}, {C, 0.9, 0.9}} *)
```

**Using `Chop`:**

```
ClearAll[cutoffFuncColE];
cutoffFuncColE[threshold_, inputlist_, col_] := 
 Module[{tmp = inputlist}, tmp[[All, col]] = Chop[tmp[[All, col]], threshold]; tmp]

dataColE = dataCol;
cutoffFuncColE[0.5, dataColE, 2]
(* {{A, 0, 0.3}, {B, 0, 0.6}, {C, 0.9, 0.9}} *)
```

**Using `MapAt` and `UnitStep`:**

```
ClearAll[cutoffFuncColF];
cutoffFuncColF[threshold_, inputlist_, col_] := 
 Module[{mm = inputlist}, mm = MapAt[# UnitStep[# - threshold] &, mm, {All, col}]; mm]

dataColF = dataCol;
cutoffFuncColE[0.5, dataColF, 2]
(*  {{A, 0, 0.3}, {B, 0, 0.6}, {C, 0.9, 0.9}} *)
```

**Using `ReplacePart` and `Chop`:**

```
ClearAll[cutoffFuncColG];
cutoffFuncColG[threshold_, inputlist_, col_] := 
             ReplacePart[inputlist, {i_, col} :> Chop[inputlist[[i, col]], threshold]]

dataColG = dataCol;
cutoffFuncColG[0.5, dataColG, 2]
(*  {{A, 0, 0.3}, {B, 0, 0.6}, {C, 0.9, 0.9}} *)
```

Comment: was going to post an answer using `Clip`...never knew about `Threshold`!

Comment: @kguler Arrg I was so close to your first example, I tried holdrest but forgot to put the LHS of the expression in as I was so focussed on the RHS.  How embarassing.  thank you for such a complete answer.

Comment: @GordonCoale, i know the feeling:) Thank you for the Accept.

Answer (score 3):

To complement some of the other answers here is one using `Clip`

```
ClearAll[cutoffFuncCol];

cutoffFuncCol[threshold_, inputlist_, col_] := 
 Module[{tmp = inputlist}, 
  tmp[[All, col]] = 
   Clip[tmp[[All, col]], {threshold, \[Infinity]}, {0, \[Infinity]}];
  tmp]

cutoffFuncCol[0.5, dataCol, 2]
(* {{A, 0, 0.3}, {B, 0, 0.6}, {C, 0.9, 0.9}} *)
```

Comment: (+1) nice way to get a single-sided `Clip`. (The only way i could think of to get `Clip` to do job was `Clip[#, {threshold, threshold}, {0, #}] & /@ tmp[[All, col]]`)

Comment: @kguler thanks. it is amazing what you can learn here. I never knew there was `Threshold` but it's been there since 8!

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I actually used this version as was the first I used that gave me a dynamic output, but marked Kgulers as being the most useful.

Answer (score 1):

This can be nicely handled with `ReplaceAt` (since V 13.3)

```
list = {{a, 0.1, 0.3}, {b, 0.4, 0.6}, {c, 0.9, 0.9}};

ReplaceAt[x_ /; x < 0.5 :> 0, {All, 2}] @ list
```

{{a, 0, 0.3}, {b, 0, 0.6}, {c, 0.9, 0.9}}

```
cut[th_, dt_, co_] := ReplaceAt[x_ /; x < th :> 0, {All, co}] @ dt

cut[1, list, 3]
```

{{a, 0.1, 0}, {b, 0.4, 0}, {c, 0.9, 0}}

Answer (score 0):

Using `RaplaceAll`:

```
cut[mat_, col_, rule_] := (# /. #[[All, col]] -> #[[All, col]] /. rule) &@mat
```

Testing `cut`:

```
cut[list, 2, x_ /; x < 0.5 :> 0]

(*{{a, 0, 0}, {b, 0, 0.6}, {c, 0.9, 0.9}}*)
```