# getting zero for special positions in a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Here is a list:

```
list = {{1, 2, 3, 2, 3}, {3, 1, 1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 1, 3, 2}, {1, 2, 1, 1, 1}};
```

I wish to have all elements be zero except the first and the fourth in each row: desired:

```
list={{1, 0, 0, 2, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 2, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 3, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0}};
```

I have written:

```
Do[
  Do[
     If[Position[list, list[[i, j]]] != {i, 1} && 
      Position[list, list[[i, j]]] != {i, 4}, list[[i, j]] = 0]
     , {i, 1, 4}]
    ,{j, 1, 5}]
```

But it doesn't work correctly. Is there any way to reach this goal?

Comment: `list[[All, {2, 3, 5}]] = 0`

Comment: Amazing and Inteligent

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3069/121

Comment: closely related: [Replacing columns of a matrix with zeros](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61219/106)

Comment: I find this solution from MarcoB the fastest with a large packed array. Using ReplacePart is very slow, it takes 100 times longer than MarcoB's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
list.DiagonalMatrix[{1, 0, 0, 1, 0}]
```

or

```
Inner[Times, list, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, List] // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
 3 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
 3 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

It may also be done as follows using [Inner](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inner.html.en) (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147810/106)):

```
Inner[Times, list, DiagonalMatrix[{1, 0, 0, 1, 0}]] // MatrixForm
```

With [Dot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html.en) and [SparseArray](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html.en):

```
list.SparseArray[{ {1, 1} -> 1, {4, 4} -> 1}, {5, 5}] // MatrixForm
```

In 'pseudocode':

```
newmat = oldmat.SparseArray[{ {<col-position-old>, <col-position-new>} -> 1,
          ...}, {< total-cols-old >, <total-cols-new>}]
```

For example, to create a new list with `col-1-old -> col-4-new, col-4-old -> col-1-new, col-3-old -> col-2-new`, and entries in all other columns equal to zero:

```
list1 // #.SparseArray[{ {1, 4} -> 1, {4, 1} -> 1, {3, 2} -> 
   1}, {Dimensions[#][[2]], 5}] & // MatrixForm
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 2 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 2 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
 3 & 1 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 5):

To preserve the original list you could do

```
 res = list;
 res[[All, {2, 3, 5}]] = 0;
 res // MatrixForm
```

Or

```
MapAt[0&, list, {All, {2, 3, 5}}] // MatrixForm
```

Or (thanks @kglr)

```
ReplacePart[list, {{_, 2 | 3 | 5} -> 0}] // MatrixForm
```

All give

[image]

Comment: (+1) you can make the second one shorter using `MapAt[0&,...]`.

Comment: Thanks - just was doing it ;)

Comment: and for the last one: `ReplacePart[list, {{_, 2 | 3 | 5} -> 0}]`:)

Comment: Indeed - how nice!!! Never have seen this form before. Do you want to post it as another answer or should I update?

Comment: eldo, i suggest you should update.

Comment: is `MapAt[0/#&,..]` a typo?  `MapAt[0&,..]` should work, no?

Comment: Oh, yes - thanks again :)