# Applying Rest and Most to sublists of list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of lists

```
proof = List[{-1, 2, 3, -1}, {-1, 2, 4, -1}, {-1, 7, 9, -1}, {-1, 7, 2, -1}, 
  {-1, 3, 9, -1}, {-1, 7, 9, -1}, {-1, 5, 9, -1}];
```

I would like to obtain the same list discarding the first and last entry of each sublist (those marked with -1.

```
Rest[Most[proof[[1]]]]
```

works for one of the lists, but when I tried

```
Rest[Most[proof[[All]]]]
```

it doesn't work and the output is the same as

```
Rest[Most[proof]]
```

(it discards the two external sublists).

I could use

```
proof = Rest[Reap[Do[Sow[Rest[Most[proof[[k]] ]]], {k,1,7}]]]
```

Rest is used to discard a NULL result and this returns a triple nested list. Is there an easier/elegant way of doing this?

Comment: `Rest[Most[#]& /@ proof` or equivalently  `Map[Rest[Most[#]&,proof]`

Comment: There is also `Drop[proof, None, {1, -1, 3}]`

Comment: `proof.SparseArray[Band[{2, 1}] -> 1, {4, 2}]`.   See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/149773/106)

Answer (score 12):

```
proof[[All, 2;;-2]] (* Shortest and most likely to be the fastest *)
Rest /@ Most /@ proof
Rest @* Most /@ proof (* thanks: Bob Hanlon *)
Composition[Rest, Most] /@ proof
ArrayPad[proof, {{0}, -1}]
Cases[proof, {_, x___, _} :> {x}]
Replace[proof, {_, a___, _} :> {a}, 1] (* thanks: eldo *)
ReplacePart[proof, {{_, 1}, {_,-1}}:> Nothing]
Extract[proof, {All, 2 ;; -2}] (* version 10+ only *)
MapAt[Nothing, proof, {{All, {1,-1}}}] (* version 10+ only *)
Drop[RotateLeft /@ proof, None, -2]
```

all give

> {{2, 3}, {2, 4}, {7, 9}, {7, 2}, {3, 9}, {7, 9}, {5, 9}}

And, for fun, so does

```
#[[2 ;; -2]] & @ proof
```

> [image]

Comment: The last can be written more compactly as `Rest@*Most /@ proof`

Comment: Thank you @Bob. Still in version 9 here. I will add your suggestion.

Comment: For completeness: `Replace[proof, {_, a___, _} :> {a}, 2]`

Comment: Thank you @eldo. Added a few more.

Comment: While it is fun to find as many ways as possible to do a certain thing, it might also be helpful to the OP to note which method should be considered the optimal for large data. For OP's problem, it doesn't really matter, of course, but I would like to chip in that `proof[[All, 2 ;; -2]]` should be considered preferable for general arrays of data.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit, good point.

Comment: @eldo Don't you mean `Replace[. . ., 1]`?

Comment: Oh yes, thanks :)

Comment: A shorter syntax: `ArrayPad[proof, {{0}, -1}]`.  Speaking of syntax I notice that you replaced `All` with `;;`; despite being a leading proponent of code brevity I prefer `All` because it costs but a single character for backward-compatibility and explicitness.

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Wizard. Changed  both.

Answer (score 2):

For your special list (- + + ... + -)

```
Pick[#, Sign @ #, 1]& @ proof
```

> {{2, 3}, {2, 4}, {7, 9}, {7, 2}, {3, 9}, {7, 9}, {5, 9}}

Comment: As the OP,*I would like to obtain the same list discarding the first and last entry of each sublist.* It is not a good solution.But anyway,it is a witty usage of `Sign`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SequenceCases[proof, {{_, x__, _}} :> {x}];
(* {{2, 3}, {2, 4}, {7, 9}, {7, 2}, {3, 9}, {7, 9}, {5, 9}} *)

ReplaceList[proof, {___, {_, a__, _}, ___} :> {a}] (* one of the many ways *)
(* {{2, 3}, {2, 4}, {7, 9}, {7, 2}, {3, 9}, {7, 9}, {5, 9}} *)

proof /. {_, x__Integer, _} :> {x}
(* {{2, 3}, {2, 4}, {7, 9}, {7, 2}, {3, 9}, {7, 9}, {5, 9}} *)

(* since only first and last entries are -1, you can do*)
DeleteCases[proof, -1, 2]
or 
DeleteCases[proof, Except[Integer, -1], 2]
(* {{2, 3}, {2, 4}, {7, 9}, {7, 2}, {3, 9}, {7, 9}, {5, 9}} *)
```